# Reset Windows 8 (Partitions)

Tags: partitioning, windows-8.1, reset

Will Windows 8.1 reset tool erase all the partitions or only the one on which windows 8.1 is located? In case if there is data on one partition and windows 8.1 is on the other partition? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It will format the partition it is on.

Per Microsoft:

> You'll be asked to choose whether you want to erase data quickly or thoroughly. If you choose to erase data quickly, some data might be recoverable using special software. If you choose to erase data thoroughly, this will take longer but it makes recovering data less likely.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc